# Best way to apply branding to SharePoint mysites

Tags: branding, mysite

I would like to know the best way to apply sharepoint branding to mysites in both on prem and office 365, do we use feature stapling or we use a provider hosted app for that? what's the best approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The supported approach to customize My Sites is to design a Feature
>   and then use Feature Stapling to associate that Feature with the site
>   definition. For example, you might design a Feature that uploads and
>   uses a custom master page for My Sites, and specifies certain Web
>   Parts that you want available for users on their My Sites.

I would go with feature stapling and for the SPO i would go for hosted app.

Please read more over here:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262706(v=office.14).aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vesku/archive/2014/03/02/sharepoint-online-solution-pack-for-branding-and-provisioning-released.aspx